# Как понять когда злоупотребляю фрагментами?

Tags: java, android

Попался проект и есть время на рефакторинг.Меня смущает то что у одного `activity` около 10-15 `fragment`-ов.Это нормально ? Как понять мне здесь использовать `activity`  или `fragment` ?какие призники того что злоупотребил `fragment`-ами?

Comment: Опишите более подробно, может это Activity с дровером и фрагменты отвечают каждый за свой функционал, есть поддержка планшета?

Comment: single activity app - новый тренд, так что все ок, ну если с навигацией все тоже в порядке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да легко, воспринимай `Activity`, как контейнер для фрагментов, весь функционал на себя берут они. Раздели приложение на этапы (например, регистрация (для нее одну активность), главный экран (еще одна активность)).

Можно сделать вообще одну активность и понаделать много фрагментов. Главное, чтобы потом это активность не превратилась в мусорку, где огромное кол-во строк кода по переключению фрагментов.